# Tensorflow MKL-DNN build in Ubuntu silently produces erroneus results

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, intel-mkl

I have built Tensorflow 1.6.0-rc0 from source in Ubuntu 16.04 with MKL-DNN support following [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#tensorflow_with_intel_mkl_dnn). The build proceeds without any problem. Testing it with keras 2.1.3 on a simple convnet from [this example](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.2-using-convnets-with-small-datasets.ipynb) "as is" is two times slower than with the non-MKL build.

Now, tuning the MKL parameters as recommended in [the guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#tensorflow_with_intel_mkl_dnn) leads to almost 2 times speedup over the non-MKL build. But produces complete nonsense in terms of accuracy (and loss):

[image: Erroneous results from Tensorflow MKL-DNN build]

This comes with no errors or warnings from the console. The MKL parameters were tuned as follows:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=K.tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)))
os.environ["KMP_BLOCKTIME"] = "0"
os.environ["KMP_AFFINITY"] = "granularity=fine,verbose,compact,1,0"
```

The CPU is an i7-4790K.

For reference, results obtained from a run without tuning the MKL parameters are as expected:

[image: Correct results from Tensorflow]

Did anyone come across a similar issue? Just to check it against the community before firing an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get such flat accuracy if the parameter "inter_op_parallelism_threads" is 2.

Given below is a modified version of the MKL tuning parameters that might speed up your code:

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=<Number.of Cores>, inter_op_parallelism_threads=2, allow_soft_placement=True,  device_count = {'CPU': <Number.of Cores>})
session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "<Number.of Cores>"
os.environ["KMP_BLOCKTIME"] = "30"
os.environ["KMP_SETTINGS"] = "1"
os.environ["KMP_AFFINITY"]= "granularity=fine,verbose,compact,1,0"
```

eg :

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=8, inter_op_parallelism_threads=2, allow_soft_placement=True,  device_count = {'CPU': 8})
session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "8"
os.environ["KMP_BLOCKTIME"] = "30"
os.environ["KMP_SETTINGS"] = "1"
os.environ["KMP_AFFINITY"]= "granularity=fine,verbose,compact,1,0"
```

Since certain optimization parameters works differently for different code, you could also play around with the parameters above to see a better speed up

Comment: Thanks @anju-paul for your solution, I could overcome the problem with it. In the meanwhile, in the recent Tensorflow commits the problem seems to have been solved: the MKL tuning parameters as suggested in the Tensorflow guide yield both plausible numerical results and the speedup, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16898